# Can I access compiled node data in a custom AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive that checks the value of the content inside it to decide if certain classes should be applied to the element, and to format the content (probably by forcing the content into a filter if the directive is applied).

I'd like the syntax to call the directive to be as follows

`<div my-directive>{{foo}}</div>`
and output something like `<div ng-class='a?b:c'>{{foo | myFilter }}</div>`

I know it's possible to do this by using `<div my-directive='foo'></div>` but I want to know if my preferred way is possible for consistency across the application.

When I try to access `element.text()` inside the post-link function, I just get `{{foo}}` instead of the rendered value. Is there a way to access the value of the directive node's content after it's been bound to HTML?

Comment: Say $scope.foo = 'bar', do you want to output `{{foo | myFilter}}` or `{{'bar' | myFilter}}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to get the value that your `{{foo}}` expression evaluates to inside your directive, you could use a combination of `$eval` and the `$interpolate` service, like so:

```
var fooValue = scope.$eval($interpolate(elem.text()));
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgfH3/) to demonstrate.